# CodenameOne simulation not finding Theme.res

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, codenameone

I'm new to codename one and attempting a brand new installation and have not been able to run the simulator.

I've installed eclipse Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2) Build id: 20171218-0600
with Java 1.8.0_162 on windows 7 enterprise service pack 1 and am experiencing the following exception which seems related to

```
[EDT] 0:0:0,64 - Exception: java.io.IOException - /theme.res not found
java.io.IOException: /theme.res not found
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.open(Resources.java:740)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openLayered(Resources.java:704)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openLayered(Resources.java:668)
    at com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.initFirstTheme(UIManager.java:1827)
    at com.drb.test01.MyApplication.init(MyApplication.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:117)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1129)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:924)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.drb.test01.MyApplication.start(MyApplication.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:123)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1129)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:924)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

I've followed these threads and applied all suggestions with no success. Can I provide more information?

One strange thing I noticed is on the New CodenameOne Project window has a grayed out Java 8 Project checkbox and a message underneath "Java 8 project requires a newer Eclipse version.

Comment: It seems that Codename One isn't detecting the JDK 8 you are using. Are you sure this is the JDK picked by Eclipse? Make sure the JDK is specified in the `eclipse.ini` file and recreate the project: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Comment: JAVA_HOME was set properly, but eclipse.ini was not!

Comment: Adding
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin\javaw.exe so I made it the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add -vm to my eclipse.ini did the trick:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
C:\Users\daveb\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
```

> ```
> -vm
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin\javaw.exe**
> ```

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```